# Akka broadcast: get the first reply and discard others

Tags: java, akka, broadcast

I have a `CalculationSupervisor` actor with a worker pool.
Each time I need to do some calculation the `CalculationSupervisor` broadcasts a `CalculationRequest` to the workers using a router.

I need to get a result of the fastest calculation and ignore other results.

`CalculationSupervisor` looks as follows:

```
public class CalculationSupervisor extends AbstractActor {

    private Router router = new Router(new RoundRobinRoutingLogic());

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(CalculationSupervisor.class, CalculationSupervisor::new);
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(RegisterWorker.class, registration -> {
                    final String workerName = registration.name();
                    final ActorRef worker = 
                        context().actorOf(Worker.props(workerName), workerName);
                    router = router.addRoutee(worker);
                })
                .match(CalculationRequest.class, (request) -> {
                    router.route(new Broadcast(request), self());
                })
                .match(CalculationResult.class, (result) -> {
                    // process only the first (the fastest) result
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

What is the best pattern to implement the logic of discarding messages that come after the first (the fastest) result come in?

Answer (score 0):

If your supervisor is processing multiple requests, a simple approach is to keep a `Map` that holds pairs of request IDs and the number of responses received for a request. The supervisor inspects this map and processes a reply only if, at the time of processing, the number of replies for that particular request ID is zero. Furthermore, to prevent the map from growing indefinitely, the supervisor deletes the entry from the map if the number of results equals the pool size:

```
public class CalculationSupervisor extends AbstractActor {
    ...
    private int poolSize = 0;
    private Map<Long, Integer> numReplies = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(RegisterWorker.class, registration -> {
                ...
                poolSize = poolSize + 1;
            })
            .match(CalculationRequest.class, request -> {
                numReplies.putIfAbsent(request.getId(), 0);
                router.route(new Broadcast(request), self());
            })
            .match(CalculationResult.class, result -> {
                Long requestId = result.getRequestId();
                if (numReplies.contains(requestId)) {
                    int num = numReplies.get(requestId);
                    if (num == 0) {
                        // process only the first (the fastest) result
                        ...
                        numReplies.put(requestId, 1);
                    } else {
                        if (num + 1 == poolSize)
                            numReplies.remove(requestId);
                        else
                            numReplies.put(requestId, num + 1);
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();
    }
}
```

There are two assumptions with the above approach:

1. A request ID is available in both the `CalculationRequest` and `CalculationResult` classes (in this example the ID is a `Long`; use whatever is appropriate).
2. The routees are registered with the supervisor before requests are sent.

An even simpler solution is to not use a router, in which case the `CalculationSupervisor` would not need to coordinate multiple results for the same request. Since you're discarding all but the earliest result for every request, it doesn't make sense to use a router in the first place.

Comment: There is a lot of requests coming into CalculationSupervisor and I'd like to process them all of them. In your approach, if I get CalculationResult for any of incoming CalculationRequest's I stop processing results for other requests. Your solution can be extended using some Map storing calculation requests identifiers and their status. This is my original thought, but I'd like to find more elegant solution :)